# Put Folder with All Subdirs in Auto Py to Exe

Tags: python-3.x, windows, auto-py-to-exe

I'm currently trying to compile a large project, which has a lot of folders with a lot of subdirs and subfiles.

These files all need to be in the right folder with the right name.
In the main folder where also the .py file is, are 2 folders with all the files.

The problem is:
I need to add all these in the .exe file. These are Like 170MB, So adding them all per hand is not an option.

It is also important that everything is in one .exe file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: yes,  but what have you tried so far ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Within the "Additional Files" section, there is a button to add a folder - have you used this? Try initially packaging to "One Directory" so you can see where the files ended up (giving you an opportunity to try different things and see where they end up)

Comment: Yeah, I`ve been Using that All the Time, but if i Add a Folder, it Just Puts an Empty Folder in there, instead of the Folder with All the Files in it.